# Cut corners css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a cut corner in CSS. 
With the following code:

```
.cutCorner:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: -2px;
    top: 1491px;
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 50px solid #302D45;
    border-left: 1455px solid transparent;
}
```

Now I would like the background of this be:

```
background: radial-gradient(50% 70%, #62729B 51%, #4C3A6E 100%), linear-gradient(-180deg, rgba(124,83,169,0.50) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.63) 100%), rgba(68,65,90,0.50);
```

How can this be done? Ideally it should match the div below it, for an example check out the website: http://matthijsotterloo.com/panda_courses/ (scroll down to the part saying: "Learn the latest web technologies."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's *your* site. Why don't you just look at how you did it?

Comment: I just want to know how I can make the background match the background of the gradient div....

Answer (score 1):

Just use `border-radius` tag in css.
eg:-

```
border-radius:25px;
```

Comment: I just want to know how I can make the background match the background of the gradient div....

Answer (score 0):

For the best cross-browser support you can use the following code:

```
/* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
-webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

/* Firefox 1-3.6 */
-moz-border-radius: 12px; 

/* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
border-radius: 12px;
```

Comment: I just want to know how I can make the background match the background of the gradient div....